# How do I number my table with each number colspanned to the first cell of each row?

Tags: html, css

I have a leaderboard and everything in my table body is pushed one to the right. I am trying to colspan the first number in each row with the player name. Since the number gets inserted into the table from my CSS file is there any way I can colspan in CSS? I have tried to colspan with negative numbers in the HTML file but that failed to work. I am pretty new to HTML and CSS so sorry if this is a stupid question any help would be greatly appreciated

```css
.bodyy{
    background-color: rgb(146, 144, 144);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
    
}

 .table-style{
    width: 40%;
     margin: 50px auto;
    background-color: white;
    
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing: 1rem;
    
    
}

.table-style thead tr td{
    border:none;
    
    
}

table tbody {
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
  }
  
  table tbody tr::before {
    display: table-cell;
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
    content: counter(rowNumber) "";
    
  }

 .head-style{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    
    
    
}

.body-style{
    
    border: solid 2px lightgrey;
    border-top: none;

    


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Stats</title>
        

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="styles.css">
    </head>

<body class="bodyy" >
    <table class="table-style" border= "1" cellpadding="10px">
        
        <thead class="head-style">
            <tr>
                <td>Player</td>
                <td>PT</td>
                <td>G</td>
                <td>A</td>
                <td>HITS</td>
                <td>GP</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="body-style" >
            <tr>
                <td>Player1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Player2</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Player3</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED** based on clarifications on comments

You need to tell the header column that it will occupy more than one column.  In this case, it will be the width of 2 columns.  Like this:

```
<th colspan="2">Player</th>
```

**Update 2**

To remove the line between the number and the first column, use CSS similar to this:

```
table tbody tr::before {
  display: table-cell;
  counter-increment: rowNumber;
  content: counter(rowNumber) "";
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

table tbody tr td{
  border-left: 0px;
}
```

**See updated demo:**

```css
.table-style {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 1rem;  
}

.table-style thead tr th {
  border: none;
}

table tbody {
  counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

table tbody tr::before {
  display: table-cell;
  counter-increment: rowNumber;
  content: counter(rowNumber) "";
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

table tbody tr td{
  border-left: 0px;
}

.head-style {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.body-style {
  border: solid 2px lightgrey;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-style" border="1" cellpadding="10px">

  <thead class="head-style">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Player</th>
      <th>PT</th>
      <th>G</th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>HITS</th>
      <th>GP</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="body-style">
    <tr>
      <td>Player1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Player2</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Player3</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You must have misunderstood my question I apologize if I worded it oddly. Im trying to merge the # column and the Player column using colspan so the numbers and the player name share the same cell. Can this be accomplished?

Comment: @skankhunt42 See updated answer

Comment: That's perfect for what I was looking for in the thead. Is it possible to do the same thing for the tbody? I still am looking to merge the cell of the number to the left of the players name together with the players name so there is not a line separating them.

Comment: The line/border can be removed with CSS - if you are going to merge the content of the two 'cells' then why put them in separate cells to begin with?  Why not put the content in the same cell? (and avoid adding columns that are not needed)

Comment: That was the problem I was having. Im not sure how to insert the content into the same cell.

Comment: In the CSS file the class "table tbody tr::before" inserts it. I'm just stumped on how to insert the number into the player cell

Comment: You can remove the border of the cell with CSS, see updated answer

Comment: Oh god the answer was so simple; I was so caught up in inserting it into the same cell. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can't insert it into the same cell because your CSS was adding it to before the Row (`tr::before`)